# Android GCM - How to remove bad device tokens from my (third party) database?

Tags: php, android, json, google-cloud-messaging, android-devicetoken

We have about 900 Android device tokens in our database for GCM push notifications.

I use this PHP function to send the push instruction to the GCM server:

```
function send_android_push($android_gcm_reg_ids, $title, $message, $activityToLaunch) {

    global $ANDROID_GCM_API_KEY, $TESTING, $TEST_ANDROID_DEVICE_REG_ID;

    if ($TESTING) {
        $android_gcm_reg_ids = [
            $TEST_ANDROID_DEVICE_REG_ID
        ];
    }

    $url = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

    $data = array(
        "title" => $title,
        "message" => $message,
        "activityToLaunch" => $activityToLaunch,
    );

    $post = array(
        'registration_ids' => $android_gcm_reg_ids,
        'data' => $data
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $ANDROID_GCM_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        $result .= "<br />GCM error: " . curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

Here is a snippet of the JSON content returned by that function/GCM:

```
{
   "multicast_id":5609284883833846123,
   "success":493,
   "failure":401,
   "canonical_ids":20,
   "results":[
      {
         "registration_id":"BPA91bHP29l2j6NPOldcpAvJCJBGk8oQFErfwuh93cxF8ajJJqBlVGqFcxMDEAc2LL2GKwmP86of49UgBTMycB5IdYergWRBETDNUrnzXX_55FgstCZiauPeD7MokIIPOFoOyW9vCRiBqZhlzLCuSnJ1ENFYtIh_PQ",
         "message_id":"0:1462275569015808%814cce86f9fd7ece"
      },
      {
         "registration_id":"BPA91bHP29l2j6NPOldcpAvJCJBGk8oQFErfwuh93cxF8ajJJqBlVGqFcxMDEAc2LL2GKwmP86of49UgBTMycB5IdYergWRBETDNUrnzXX_55FgstCZiauPeD7MokIIPOFoOyW9vCRiBqZhlzLCuSnJ1ENFYtIh_PQ",
         "message_id":"0:1462275569015815%814cce86f9fd7ece"
      },
      {
         "message_id":"0:1462275569014983%814cce86f9fd7ece"
      },
      {
         "error":"NotRegistered"
      },
      {
         "message_id":"0:1462275569017976%814cce86f9fd7ece"
      },
etc., etc.
```

It seems to be saying I have device tokens in my database that are `NotRegistered` but, as you can see, it doesn't tell me which device token isn't registered so I am wondering how I can mark it as obsolete in my database?

I thought that maybe the elements of the JSON array returned by the GCM server might correspond to the `$android_gcm_reg_ids` array I pass into my `send_android_push(...)` function but that can't be the case because the **BPA91bHP29l2j6NPOldcpAvJCJBGk8oQFErfwuh93cxF8ajJJqBlVGqFcxMDEAc2LL2GKwmP86of49UgBTMycB5IdYergWRBETDNUrnzXX_55FgstCZiauPeD7MokIIPOFoOyW9vCRiBqZhlzLCuSnJ1ENFYtIh_PQ** `registration_id` appears numerous times in the GCM JSON array - despite that same token only appearing once in my database.

So presumably there must be some other way of removing obsolete device tokens from my database??

And the reason I am concerned about this is because I have had the situation before (with iOS) where sending bad device tokens (to APNS) resulted in the push notification not being sent to valid devices, and I would obviously like to keep my database in a good state anyway.

I can't find anything to help on the web, so maybe I am missing or getting wrong something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know which registration token is causing this, you have to map to the same index in your `registration_ids` array of your request to GCM.

Here from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream):

> Results: Array of objects representing the status of the messages processed. The objects are listed in the same order as the request
>   (i.e., for each registration ID in the request, its result is listed
>   in the same index in the response).

Comment: So, that *should* be the case. But, as mentioned in my question, that isn't what's happening...

Comment: Are checking if there's at least one `canonical_id` in the GCM response ? If so then you should look for a `registration_id` inside the results array.

Comment: As you can see in the snippet in my question, the values of `canonical_ids` is `20,`. But look at the `results` array - the values of `registration_id` from the first two rows is identical - i.e., they do not correspond to the `registration_ids` that I *sent* to GCM.

Comment: First of all, the `registration_id` inside `results` is NOT necessarily the same as the one from your request. It just tells you what's the current `canonical_id`. The fact that it's the same, means that you had two `registration_ids` in your request that maps to a single canonical_id (probably because they were generated by the same device). You should never rely on the registration_id received from the device and stored in your database; instead you should always replace it with canonical_id received from GCM (and make future requests with that id)

Comment: For anyone else needing a bit more clarification of `canonical_id` and `canonical_ids`, there is a good post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27073013/1617737 . :-)

Comment: After just accepted your answer, I have noticed that the array I sent to GCM contained 944 token IDs. But the `results` array I got back from GCM has only 924 elements. The difference (20) is the same as the number of `canonical_ids` reported, but because of the mismatch in array lengths, I cannot simply map the indexes as you suggested...