# Android: Google FCM canonical ids -how to reproduce in non production or tests

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to write test cases to validate whether canonical IDs successfully replaced  the original token without mocking.

I am unable to reproduce this from an android device.   I tried to send my push notification with old registration id , I am only getting NotRegistered from FCM.

Any suggestions as to how to reproduce?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072824/how-to-get-canonical-id-from-gcm

Comment: You get the Canonical ID back once you made a callback to their web service, hence I do not know how could you do that in a test environment without mocking

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I think I read the SO question before. The SO answer or google does not tell when FCM/GCM thinks the ids are out of sync leading to canonical id generation. I am looking for any hack sort of solution so that i can test before pushing the code to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you no longer have to expect working with Canonical IDs (although having your server/client to be able to handle them would be good). Ever since FCM came into play, I haven't seen Canonical IDs being used anymore.

A portion from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41688081/4625829):

> In FCM, it seems the Canonical IDs are no longer used (or at the very least extremely rarely) because of how the [Instance ID service](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/) works. To put it simply, the service works that there would only be one valid token per App Instance.
>
> If the older token expires (for whichever reason), FCM triggers a tokenRefresh event where you would get a new registration token, and where you must also handle it accordingly (in `onTokenRefresh()`).

Comment: Thanks. I received kind of the same answer from google support