# Firebase Functions not delivering notification in iOS 11 - Error Message: canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios11, google-cloud-functions

I was getting the notifications in iOS 10, but it stop working in iOS 11. I've read similar questions were people said the solution is to use pod FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.0, so I downgraded to that version, but the notification is still not showing.

The functions log reads canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0 any idea of what this is?
[Function Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FflY.png)

Also, I'm using FirebaseMessaging 2.0.2

Comment: The log shows `successCount:1` as well. This means that the payload was actually sent. I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47246989/4625829). Seems possibly similar (notifications not working on iOS11)..

Comment: Thanks for the link AL. I read that thread and I had everything in place except the .p8 certificate. Firebase requires that file now instead of the .p12 file. Also to clarify the "canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0" line on the function log is not an indicator of a problem. I'm getting the notifications now and it still reads canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0.

Comment: Hi @VaneS. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41688081/4625829)