# Retrieve FCM canonical_id in v1 API

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm migrating to the FCM v1 API (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages) from the legacy API (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) to send push notifications.

I want to know if is there **some way to retrieve the `canonical_id`** related to the token (`registration_id`) just like in the [legacy API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table5).

I have found nothing about it in the docs, only that the result is a [Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Message) object, and if an error occurs it returns a [FcmError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/FcmError) Object.

If I can't retrieve the `canonical_id` I think I would end up receiving errors of invalid / not registered token after some time (or am I wrong?), and would have to invalidate them in my database, if the user doesn't use the app during a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, canonical_ids haven't been used since the legacy api. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41688081/4625829).

Registration tokens don't get invalidated on a regular basis, just on a few [scenarios](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService.html#onTokenRefresh()), where `onTokenRefresh()` is actually called and thus must be handled on the client side (resend the new token towards your server).