# Can expired registration tokens be valid again?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

My question is this I implementing a system to clear our servers of expired GCM registration tokens.

1. Once a registrationID is rejected by GCM as not registered or expired can it ever become valid again ? For APNS in iOS this can occur, but it cannot happen for GCM correct?
2. Once a client updates its registration tokens with GCM and our servers try to send notifications downstream it can receive a result with a canonical ID listing the new registration ID. How long is the old registration ID valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. Once the token expires, a different valid token takes it's place --
   triggering `onTokenRefresh()` on the corresponding client's side. It's actually expected for the developers to immediately remove the expired token from where they keep it, and replace it with the new one.
2. [Canonical IDs are AFAIK, no longer used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41687344/4625829).